# How to change the Date Format

Tags: excel

I Have 1 Column where there dates are not Uniform.
I am using as a ref to derive one Column.

the date in column is

17/09/2010    i am changing the this format to 09/17/2010 by using =MID(H3,4,3)& MID(H3,1,3)&MID(H3,7,4).

But there are some dates Which are like 9/3/2007 now i want a formula to match all the dates.

Please Help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that, due to your regional settings, `17/09/2010` isn't recognised as a date and `9/3/2007` is recognised as March 9th, while you want September 3rd.

If you treat your input as text, you can parse it properly into a date with this formula, which I just tested:

```
=DATE(MID(H3,FIND("/",H3,4)+1,4),
      MID(H3,FIND("/",H3)+1,FIND("/",H3,4)-FIND("/",H3)-1),
      LEFT(H3,FIND("/",H3)-1))
```

Make sure H3 is formatted as Text, else the string functions (`MID`, `LEFT`) risk not working as expected. The cell containing that formula should be formatted as Date: `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

why not change the cell property of the whole column to User Defined like mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: That doesn't help if `17/09/2010` isn't recognised as a date in the first place, due to the user's regional settings.